# How to users can login, update their tasks with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I make a Google Web App with Google Apps Script so users can update their work tasks on each user.
When the user logs in with their account in the login form, they will be redirected to the TASK UPDATE PANEL page. On this page, their information will be displayed in Sheet Data columns B, C, D (NAME, Department, Date of Birth)

And here they can update their task as in columns E, F, G, H (Task 1,Task 1 completion date, Task 2, Task 2 completion date).
Tasks 1 and 2 will drop down the content like in columns E and G
The Task 1 completion date and Task 2 completion date will enter the date format.

After they update, they will update the update time in column I (Time Update).
I have written the login page but in the PageForm page, I can't output the data as shown. I've been thinking about it for a few days now but don't know how to do it. Hope anyone can help me?

I would like to send the google sheet link for everyone to refer: [SAMPLE SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SmcJb0z6wjbT9BAwiPt4WH_M2D7Gdmkqb9eg2lPh7Hs/edit?usp=sharing) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SmcJb0z6wjbT9BAwiPt4WH_M2D7Gdmkqb9eg2lPh7Hs/edit#gid=0

Comment: Comment on a design: keep in mind that any user can edit anything in spreadsheet if they have access to it. User input in Google Sheets is very unrestricted.

Comment: can you share your code?  I've done several similar projects, might can help you to find where goes wrong.

Comment: I send the link of google sheet. Please take a look at it for me. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SmcJb0z6wjbT9BAwiPt4WH_M2D7Gdmkqb9eg2lPh7Hs/edit#gid=0